# Search button or input field for search in top navbar of website?

Tags: user-behavior, user-expectation, design

i just curious about difference in effectiveness between search button and input field for search in top navbar. Is it better search button or the input field?

If you have to choose one of them, which one you choose to put on top navbar? Why?

Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In this article by Nick Babich, [Design a Perfect Search Box](https://uxplanet.org/design-a-perfect-search-box-b6baaf9599c), he suggests that if the search field is important, it should be prominent, showing the text field instead of only the button. The main reasons are:

- It can be the fastest route to discovery for users;
- Search hidden behind an icon makes search feature less noticeable;
- Search hidden increases the cost of interaction.

Comment: Thank you for the insight